# ctypes interface for derived C/C++ library

Tags: inheritance, module, include, ctypes

I have two C/C++ libraries which give interface to class `Solver` and `MultiSolver` derived from `Solver`. I want make python API to both of them **with minimum code repetition**.

This means I don't want to copy/rewrite ctypes interface to function `Solver` when writing interface to derived `MultiSolver`. Currently I see 2 solutions:

- Wrap ctypes interface into python classes with hierarchy (but not very keen to do that, because it makes an other level of indirection)
- use `exec` command [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714881/how-to-include-external-python-code-to-use-in-other-files), but I think it is not very good practice
- It is very much related to question about [inheritance of python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434332/how-to-extend-inheritance-a-module-in-python)

Here is simplified example of the problem with only few functions in the library (in reality there are many more).

### C/C++ side

`Solver.h`

```
class Solver{ public:
   void solve(){ ... };   
};
```

`MultiSolver.h`

```
#include "Solver.h"
class MultiSolver : public Solver {  public:
   void solve_multi(){ ... };   
};
```

`lib_commons.cpp`

```
extern "C"{
   void solve(){ W.solve(); };
}
```

`libSolver.cpp`

```
#include "Solver.h"
Solver W;
#include "lib_commons.cpp"
```

`libMultiSolver.cpp`

```
#include "MultiSolver.h"
MultiSolver W;
#include "lib_commons.cpp"
extern "C"{
   void solve_multi(){ W.solve_multi(); };
}
```

### Python side

`libSolver.py`

```py
import ctypes 
lib = ctypes.CDLL( path+"libSolver.so" )

lib.solve.argtypes  = [] 
lib.solve.restype   = None
def solve():
    return lib.solve()
```

`libMultiSolver.py`

```py
import ctypes 
lib = ctypes.CDLL( path+"libMultiSolver.so" )

# ========== HERE ==========
# I don't want to repeate this !!!!!
lib.solve.argtypes  = [] 
lib.solve.restype   = None
def solve():
    return lib.solve()

lib.solve_multi.argtypes  = [] 
lib.solve_multi.restype   = None
def solve_multi():
    return lib.solve_multi()
```

Comment: The design generally looks odd: the 2 libraries (each exporting a class + the wrapping function), + *MultiSolver* not inheriting *solve*.  You can also create an extension module (using *PyBind11* for example).